# Isaiah 40:3 on "preparing road for the Lord"

Tags: commentaries, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

[Isaiah 40:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.40.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> "קוֹל קוֹרֵא בַּמִּדְבָּר פַּנּוּ דֶּרֶךְ ה' יַשְּׁרוּ בָּעֲרָבָה מְסִלָּה לֵאלֹהֵינוּ׃" פנו דרך יי"

and often translated as "clear a/the road for/of the Lord". And it also says to straighten (ישרו) the route/pathway (מסלה).

I would like to know if we should take this somewhat literally or figuratively i.e. should we build a way through the wilderness and desert, or should we read panu and yaseru as a call to for example turn ourselves and get even with the Lord? I.e. What does it mean to prepare a way/route for His coming? Does this mean He will come and ‘take’ this route (Will He act and show Himself through certain events down this route as he won’t take this route physically right), or does this refer to something else?

Comment: As a general rule, we hold that the prophets speak in metaphors (Rambam's introduction to MT). We don't hold prophetic orders as Halachic rulings.

Comment: What exactly is the proposed non-metaphorical instruction? Build random highways in deserts?

Comment: @DoubleAA Just going off on a possible non-metaphorical instruction, would that be so far-fetched on a Peshat Level? Rebuilding old waste places and foundations of old on a physical level?